# Stack Overflow Careers company page Ad needs a fix

Tags: discussion, jobs, advertising

I just saw the [MidwayUSA job ad](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/MidwayUSA?c=hFLYPH2nxY5GGXss) under the "Featured Company" on the main page of Stack Overflow Careers. I noticed the top part of the letter "d", "USA" along with right-side of "A" and "Y" is ***chopped***.  Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

So, I thought of checking how are the other companies profile pages looks like and I clicked on the [Companies](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/companies) tab which brought me the list of 8741 company pages (10 profiles per page). But, the same company page ad (little skinnier and tall this time) was displayed in the right side panel. Here, the letter "M" with right-side of "A" plus the half of "Y" is chopped. Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

Upon clicking on the company ad, it shows the [company profile page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/MidwayUSA?c=hFLYPH2nxY5GGXss) with a huge cover image as shown below:

> [image]

Here everything looks okay except the right-side of the letter "A" and "Y" is *still chopped*.

It seems like the above shown cover image has been used to create the company display ad. Based on the current code:

```
<div class="-coverImage" style="background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/T62Pmm.jpg')"></div>
```

It's using the medium version 'T62Pmm.jpg' (notice 'm' before the dot) of the full-size cover image 'T62Pm.jpg'

I think fixing the cover image should fix the company page display ad issue. IMHO, displaying such a huge company logo as a cover image (and that too *chopped* one) does not make the first impression good at all. I think it would be good if the client knows about it and also the job ads that generated based on their current cover image. SO Careers company product page rightly says: "First impressions matter: Make yours count". Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! You are absolutely correct, and we'll reach out to the company to work with them on their company page.

Comment: No problem. I guess you could say thank you by Up-voting for my effort. I hate to ask this but then how would you expect me get my next-privileges without the points. Look 3 up-votes and possibly more later for your one n half line but no up-vote for me. I can't justify this. Totally demoralizing.